# Mac - List opened windows in terminal

Tags: macos, applescript, osascript

I want to list opened windows in the terminal to get x, y, width and height like `xwininfo -root -tree` for X11.

I tried:

```
osacript -e tell application "Microsoft Word" to get the bounds of the front window
```

But it's does not work for all Application and you can't specify a child (If you have two Word Document, it return the first opened).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the position of all windows:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to get the position of every window of every process'
```

The size:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to get the size of every window of every process'
```

The title:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to get the title of every window of every process'
```

Check the reference in AppleScript Editor for more properties.

Comment: Thanks but it does not work.

When I try :

osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to get the position of every window of every process'

I have this error :

execution error: System Events got an error: Access for assistive devices is disabled. (-25211)

Comment: go to system preferences -> universal access and enable "Enable access for assistive devices"

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Last question, how I can determine if the window is in the dock (hidden) or on the front ?

Comment: I found I also had to restart my terminal (iTerm) for permission to be granted (Big Sur)

Comment: In Terminal, to print a window title on each line, you can use (without triple quotes):
"""
osascript -e 'set output to ""' -e 'tell application "System Events"' -e 'repeat with proc in every process' -e 'repeat with w in every window of proc' -e 'set output to output & (name of w) & "\n"' -e 'end repeat' -e 'end repeat' -e 'end tell' -e 'output'
"""